# How to maintain a pool of users with PyTest & Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am trying to maintain a pool of Users with a parameter of availability so that PyTest can pick an available user from the list.

But I cannot figure out where to place it such that even on running multiple tests, the object doesn't get destroyed.

My User pool looks like this:

```
class User:

    def getId()

    def getPwd()

    def getAvailability()
```

Basically, I want to configure PyTest so that before starting every test, it takes the available user from the pool and changes it's status to `False`.

Any help in configuring the conftest.py would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might I didn't get your question correctly, but first idea was like that:

```
import pytest


class UsersFactory:
    _pool = [{"user": "user1", "status": True}, {"user": "user2", "status": True}, {"user": "user3", "status": True},
             {"user": "user4", "status": True}]
    _user = None

    @classmethod
    def get_user(cls):
        cls._user = cls._pool.pop(0)
        return cls._user

    @classmethod
    def back_user(cls):
        cls._user['status'] = False
        cls._pool.append(cls._user)
        cls._user = None


@pytest.fixture
def user():
    yield UsersFactory.get_user()
    UsersFactory.back_user()


def test_smth(user):
    print(user)
    assert user['status']


def test_smth2(user):
    print(user)
    assert user['status']
```

you can set scope to fixture, that your user will be set each test, function, class, package

Comment: The basic idea was this only, Can you please expand it on how I can place it in the conftest.py file and use it in a different classes (separate file) of tests?

Comment: @Vivank that one is stored in conftest.py pytest.fixture
def user():
    yield UsersFactory.get_user()
    UsersFactory.back_user()

Comment: @Vivank fixture is not imported to tests, just place test files near to conftest.py. Userfactory file can be placed to any utils dir and imported to conftest.py

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.
Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi on running test in parallel using `pytest -n 2` it's not taking the second user from the dict. 

Can you help me with it?

Comment: @Vivank it's xdist behavior, try to add `--dist loadscope` to your pytest command line